# Парсинг JSON файла и заполнение коллекции

Tags: android

Есть файл radios.json со следующим содержимым

```
{
  "radio": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Радио 1",
      "url": "ссылка",
      "image": "картинка"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Радио 2",
      "url": "ссылка",
      "image": "картинка"
    }
  ]
}
```

Есть класс модель Radio с полями title, id, url и img

Как распарсить файл json с помощью библиотеки gson и заполнить коллекцию List для дальнейшего его использования в адаптере для RecyclerView? Файл radio.json лежит в assets проекта

У меня есть такой код, но через gson вроде как можно покороче сделать это все

```
private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                InputStream in = getAssets().open("radios.json");
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return resultJson;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;

            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray radioArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("radios");

                for (int i = 0; i < radioArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = radioArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String radioTitle = object.optString("title");
                    String radioUrl = object.optString("url");
                    String radioImage = object.optString("image");

                    radios.add(new Radio(radioTitle, radioUrl, resId));
                }
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```